# Position sticky is not working with horizontal scroll in table

Tags: html, css, html-table, frontend

I am trying to make table with horizontal scroll that can freeze columns, for now I am trying to freeze one cell for tests but it won't work as intended.

This is the code I am using to freeze my cell:

```
element.style {
    position: sticky !important;
    z-index: 1000;
    top: 0;
}
```

Using this the cell won't freeze and is moving with whole table from left to right. I found this https://plnkr.co/edit/l0m9pF3His2BrKjS?preview and tried to recreate that solution in my project.

Does someone know a reason why I can't freeze this cell in place?

If I use vertical scroll the cell stays on top of other elements so the z-index: part works.

Comment: share your html code as well

Comment: down-voted and flagged for closure because the question missing details and clarity aswell as debugging details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to define `left` or `right` to make it also in the horizontal direction sticky.

**Working example:**

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

div {
    width: 200vw;
    height: 100vh;
}

span {
    position: sticky !important;
    z-index: 1000;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <span>STICKY SPAN</span>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
</div>
```